# If só retorna o primeiro resultado

Tags: php, if

Olá, estou com o problema no código onde o meu "IF" só retorna o primeiro resultado:

```
if ($aluno['janimal']="1"){
    $animal = "Réptil";}          
elseif($aluno['janimal']="2"){
    $animal ="Cavalo";}
elseif($aluno['janimal']="3"){
    $animal ="Porco";}
elseif($aluno['janimal']="4"){
    $animal ="Tartaruga";}
elseif($aluno['janimal']="5"){
    $animal ="Roedores(Coelho, Chinchila, hamster)";}
elseif($aluno['janimal']="6"){
    $animal ="Peixes";}
elseif($aluno['janimal']="7"){
    $animal ="Aves";}
elseif($aluno['janimal']="8"){
    $animal ="Gato";}
elseif($aluno['janimal']="9"){
    $animal ="Cão";}
elseif($aluno['janimal']="10"){
    $animal ="Invertebrados";}
elseif($aluno['janimal']="11"){
    $animal ="Anfibios";}
else{
    $animal ="Outros";}
```

Tem algum problema?

Eu chamo a variável "$animal" em outro momento....

Comment: Utilize dois sinal de `=`. Dessa forma `==`.

Quando você utiliza apenas um, você está informando que se a variável `$aluno['janimal']` receber o valor de `1`, então, `$animal` é igual a `Réptil`. Com dois `==` você está comparando se o valor da varável é igual a `1`

Mas com essa quantidade de `ifs` recomendo utilizar o `switch...case`

Comment: Quando eu coloco == ele da o seguinte erro: Notice: Undefined index: janimal in C:\xampp\htdocs\addemp\informacao.php on line 286

Comment: Isso significa que a variável `$animal` não possui o valor de `janimal`. Utilize a função `isset` para verificar se o valor existe. `if (isset($animal['janimal'])) { /* verifica os outros if's */ }`

Answer (score 3):

Tem que ser `==` ao invés de apenas `=`

Comment: @Inkeliz acho que sua edição acaba por alterar completamente a resposta, por mais util que seja. Esse tipo de edição que adiciona/remove elementos no post que o autor sequer citou não são recomendadas.

Comment: @Articuno, reverti.